# Importing 3ds file in ldraw (LeoCAD)

Tags: cad, ldraw

I designed a model in [LDraw/LeoCAD](https://www.leocad.org/) and exported it as `.3ds` file. I thought that I can import `.3ds` file to edit it later. Now I want to edit the model but I don't see any option to import the `.3ds` file in LeoCAD. I tried my best to open it but useless.
How can I open a `.3ds` file in LeoCAD?

Answer (score 2):

.3DS is a 3D image file format, a rendering of what you designed in LeoCAD.
All information necessary to recreate your build (i.e. what bricks to use) will be stripped from it. I suppose that theoretically this information can be recreated for small builds, but for medium-sized to large builds, this will simply be infeasible.
Hence I think it quite unlikely that it's possible to import .3ds back into LeoCAD.

Comment: Yes. How its possible? I have small model.

Comment: I believe it isn't, it's only "theoretically" possible. Unlikely the developers of LeoCad will have gone through the trouble of implementing this.